# Why does {$i \mid i \notin S_i$} lead to a contradiction when showing the set all subsets of a countably infinite set are uncountable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

In the following explanation of why all subsets of a countably infinite set are uncountable, I am not understanding why the existence of {$i \mid i \notin S_i$} leads to a contradiction:

> The set of all subsets of a countably infinite set is uncountable.
> Answer: True. Assume the sets are countable and thus each set corresponds to a natural number: $S_i$. The set {$i \mid i \notin S_i$} cannot be any of the $S_i$ 's since it differs on whether $i$ is in the set of not.

I am wondering if here there is a certain way with which we associate a set with the natural number corresponding to it such that the set {$i \mid i \notin S_i$} leads to a contradiction somehow- must $S_i$ contain $i$? What would the construction of the $S_i$ formally look like? I am at a loss to understand how this leads to a contradiction, and would appreciate if someone could elucidate this.

Comment: All subsets of a countable set are obviously countable. What is not countable is _the set_ of all subsets of a countable set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $S = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots\}$ be your countably infinite set. The $S_i$ aren't constructed. They are handed to you. They are, supposedly, a list of all the subsets of $S$. As in, whoever gave it to you is "hoping" that
$$
P(S)=\{S_1,S_2, S_3, \cdots\}
$$
(where $P$ stands for the power set.) Technically, the way this is set up, you are the one to put the indices on this list, and this gives you even more power. But it is not power we need, so we can leave the indexing up to whoever gave us the list.

Maybe $x_1\in S_1$, maybe not. Maybe $x_2\in S_2$, maybe not. It depends on the person who made the list, and how they made it.

But no matter who made the list, no matter how it's made, we can construct a subset of $S$ that's not in the list. That subset is $S_c=\{x_i\mid x_i\notin S_i\}$. Why is it not in the list? Well, $x_1$ is contained in either $S_1$ or $S_c$, but not in both. So those two sets are unequal. And $S_c$ can't be equal to $S_2$, because $x_2$ is contained in one of $S_2$ and $S_c$, but not in both. And so on. None of the $S_i$ can be equal to $S_c$, because no matter which $S_i$ you compare $S_c$ to, there is at least one element that's in one and not the other, namely $x_i$.

If someone then gives you a different list, in the hope that this time they have really nailed it down, then you will construct a different $S_c$, proving that this list is also deficient. No matter what list of subsets you get, you can always demonstrate that it is deficient (as long as the list is countable). You can always prove that it doesn't contain all subsets of $S$. And you do it with the same construction every time.

I don't see any contradiction here. Only a proof that any countable list is deficient. One could start by assuming that the list we have is indeed complete, and then construct the "counterwitness" $S_c$, and claim contradiction. But I personally don't like this extra layer of abstraction. This is a proof that any countable list necessarily must be incomplete. So that is how I will phrase the proof.

Comment: Who handed you the list? I like to think about a Math God, or maybe a Devil's advocate, trying as hard as they can to set you up to fail. They are giving you the most tricky list they can imagine. They will look into the future to see what proof you're going to write, and they will try their darnedest to give you a list that foils your attempt. It is your job as the proof writer to not give them any loopholes, and to demonstrate that there are no loopholes.

Comment: Thanks; how do we know that $i$ should have been in the original set $S$? Also, do we lose generality by talking about natural numbers belonging to the $S_i$, or were you just saying that to illustrate a specific example?

Comment: @Shmuel Good question. I think I got my lines crossed for a second there. It seems like both I and your quote assume that $S = \Bbb N$. Which is the archetypal countably infinite set, but there is no reason for this assumption. I think the easiest way to fix this is to simply index all the elements of $S$. I'll get right on correcting this in my answer.

Comment: Is it correct to view this as diagonalization given a bijective mapping from $\mathbb{N}$ to each subset of $S$ ? for each element in this mapping, starting from the first, if the first set has the first element of $S, S_1$, we don't include it in this set we are constructing; if it doesn't have it, we include it- and going forth for all natural numbers, which  $i$ assumes? And then at the end, there is proof by contradiction because if this constructed set $S_c$ was mapped from natural number $j$, then if $S_c$ had $j$, $S_c$ doesn't have $j$, and if it didn't have $j$, then it has $j$?

Comment: @Shmuel Yes, that's it.